# How do I get OS X's Keychain to remember my github rsa key?

Tags: macos, keychain, universal-remote, rsa

I've created an RSA key with a non-default key name: github_id_rsa. In order to not get the error "Permission denied (publickey)" when trying to push to or pull from [Github](http://www.github.com) I have to issue the command `ssh-add github_id_rsa`; however, this is not persistent. What do I need to do to get Keychain to remember this RSA key and to remember the passphrase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out instead of using `ssh-add github_id_rsa`, I just needed to use `ssh-add -K github_id_rsa` in order to add the identity and passphrase to my keychain.